# Algorithmic label cross references not working

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithms, algorithmic

I'm using the Latex style files of [ICML 2020](https://icml.cc/Conferences/2020/StyleAuthorInstructions), that can be found [here](https://media.icml.cc/Conferences/ICML2020/Styles/icml2020_style.zip). In particular, they supply `algorithm.sty` and `algorithmic.sty`. When I try to reference a line in an algorithm, I get a cross-reference to the algorithm itself. To make the problem even weirder, when I remove these two style files (and force my compiler to use the updated packages) the cross-reference becomes correct.

Any Ideas?

Here's a minimal working example (I kept the lines I felt are necessary):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\theHalgorithm}{\arabic{algorithm}}
\usepackage{icml2020}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\label{submission}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{This is an algorithm}
  \label{alg:the_alg}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE line number one \label{op0}
    \STATE line number two \label{op1}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
This is Line \ref{op0}, and this is Line \ref{op1}.
\end{document}
```

This code produces the following:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main problem here is on line 106 of `algorithmic.sty`:

```
106:  \newcommand{\ALC@it}{\addtocounter{ALC@line}{1}\addtocounter{ALC@rem}{1}\ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALC@rem}}{#1}}{\setcounter{ALC@rem}{0}}{}\item}
```

The line counter number is incremented using

```
\addtocounter{ALC@line}{1}
```

instead of

```
\refstepcounter{ALC@line}
```

So, it should resemble

```
106:  \newcommand{\ALC@it}{\refstepcounter{ALC@line}\addtocounter{ALC@rem}{1}\ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALC@rem}}{#1}}{\setcounter{ALC@rem}{0}}{}\item}
```

My suggestion would be to [contact the ICML](https://icml.cc/Help/Contact) and request that they change their version of `algorithmic.sty` they release with [their conference style](https://media.icml.cc/Conferences/ICML2020/Styles/icml2020_style.zip) to allow for proper referencing.

In the interim, you can define your own `\alglinelabel` macro that properly sets a `\label` that can be referenced:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\theHalgorithm}{\arabic{algorithm}}

\newcommand{\alglinelabel}{%
  \addtocounter{ALC@line}{-1}% Reduce line counter by 1
  \refstepcounter{ALC@line}% Increment line counter with reference capability
  \label% Regular \label
}

\usepackage{icml2020}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{This is an algorithm}
  \label{alg:the_alg}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE line number one \alglinelabel{op0}
    \STATE line number two \alglinelabel{op1}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
This is Line \ref{op0}, and this is Line \ref{op1}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You absolutely nailed it, thanks! I'm reaching out to the organizers as you suggested.

Comment: You are a hero! This problem is still in the ICML2021 style file ...

Comment: The problem is also in the ICML2023 style file!